# merge the dynamic tables and forming into one dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table consisting of dynamic values that get increased as more questions dynamically added:

```
Q1Avg  Q2Avg  Q3Avg  Q4Avg  Q5Avg
64     96     98     100    100
```

I have another table consists of scores, consider like each student row, scored in columns:

```
Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4  Q5
60   80  100  100  100  student1
20  100  100  100  100  student2
80  100   90  100  100  student3
80  100  100  100  100  student4
80  100  100  100  100  student5
```

I want to merge both dynamic tables, whose value get dynamically updated. Display it in below formate making use of dynamic tables:

```
Q1  Avg  Q2  Avg  Q3  Avg  Q4  Avg  Q5  Avg
60  64   80  96   100 98   100 100  100 100
```

And so on.

Comment: What do you have for your tables currently?

Comment: Show simplified HTML, please.